# Powershell - manage error when registry key not exist

Tags: powershell, registry

I hope you're well.

**Desciption**

I requiere your help regarding the following code I use and who can generate an error when registry key do not exist.

In this example:
If the key Ins_ProductVersion exist in both registry path, the code show information expected.
However, if this key do not exist, I got an error exception + the text: - Product Version: Not found!
My goal , is to only get my message and not the error exception
I was thinking that -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue will manage this situation, but not in my case it not seems

```
foreach ($path in 'HKLM:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment\', 'HKLM:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment\') {
    $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $path  -Name 'Ins_ProductVersion' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # assuming you want to exit the loop at the first successfull 'hit'
    if ($hotfix) { break }
}

if ($hotfix) {
    write-host "- Product Version: $hotfix"
}
else {
    write-host "- Product Version: Not found!"
}
```

Thanks for your helps and futur advices.
Regards,
Florian

-------------- new code version ---------------
Not working for now

1. Original key is : Version
2. Change this key like : Version1

Output can be found here :
[image: Error ouput]
code used

```
foreach ($path in 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Dropbox\Client', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Dropbox\Client') {
    $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $path  -Name 'Version' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # assuming you want to exit the loop at the first successfull 'hit'
    if ($hotfix) { break }
}

if ($hotfix) {
    write-host "- Product version: $hotfix"
}
else {
    Write-Host "- Product version : Not found"
}
```

========== SOLUTION ==========

Thanks for your help

```
foreach ($path in 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Dropbox\Client', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Dropbox\Client') {
    try {
        $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $path -Name 'Version' -ErrorAction Stop
        # assuming you want to exit the loop at the first successfull 'hit'
        if ($hotfix) { break }
    }
    catch { 
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

if ($hotfix) {
    write-host "- Product version: $hotfix"
}
else {
    Write-Host "- Product version : Not found"
}
```

Comment: retype the Name parameter in your code. Now, it doesn't match the exception message. You may have some invisible control character in there by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you receive both an exception **and** your own message is because you have defined the registry paths wrong:

`HKLM:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment` should be either

`HKLM:\SOFTWARE\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment` **OR**

`Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment`

In your code, you have now added the registry **hive** twice, where you only need the short OR long version here.

This works:

```
foreach ($path in 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment\', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment\') {
    $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $path  -Name 'Ins_ProductVersion' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # assuming you want to exit the loop at the first successfull 'hit'
    if ($hotfix) { break }
}

if ($hotfix) {
    write-host "- Product Version: $hotfix"
}
else {
    write-host "- Product Version: Not found!"
}
```

and so does this:

```
foreach ($path in 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment\', 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment\') {
    $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $path  -Name 'Ins_ProductVersion' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # assuming you want to exit the loop at the first successfull 'hit'
    if ($hotfix) { break }
}

if ($hotfix) {
    write-host "- Product Version: $hotfix"
}
else {
    write-host "- Product Version: Not found!"
}
```

without the need to wrap it inside a `try{..} catch{..}`

---

Although I do not have any exception messages, and for me the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` does exactly what is expected, you say you keep also receiving system Exception messages using the above..

In that case, you will need to add a try{..}catch{..} to figure out what exactly errors out like this:

```
foreach ($path in 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Dropbox\Client', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Dropbox\Client') {
    try {
        $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $path -Name 'Version' -ErrorAction Stop
        # assuming you want to exit the loop at the first successfull 'hit'
        if ($hotfix) { break }
    }
    catch { 
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

if ($hotfix) {
    write-host "- Product version: $hotfix"
}
else {
    Write-Host "- Product version : Not found"
}
```

Now, exceptions will be written to the screen too like

```
WARNING: Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Dropbox\Client' because it does not exist.
WARNING: Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Dropbox\Client' because it does not exist.
- Product version : Not found
```

or

```
WARNING: Property Version does not exist at path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Dropbox\Client.
WARNING: Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Dropbox\Client' because it does not exist.
- Product version : Not found
```

Comment: Hello Theo, 

Thanks for this code error, that I need to patch this :) 

Despite this error, unfortuantely, my test indicate that if registry key do not exist I got the following output: my message and system message too :(

Comment: @LEFBE If I run the code, I don't get any system exception, just your message. Please post that message so we can see what you're dealing with.

Comment: original post have been edited with screen and code

Comment: @LEFBE you have `-Name 'Version& '` in there.. I think it's complaining about that `&` character...

Comment: @LEFBE retype the Name parameter in your code. Now, it doesn't match the exception message. You may have some invisible control character in there by accident.

Comment: Hello Theo, fixed, but same behavior :(

Comment: @LEFBE Please can you try my last edit? It's weird it works for me without giving me any system exceptions. I'm on Windows 10 Pro, PowerShell version 5.1.

Comment: thanks for your time.
So in conclusion, the only solution is to use try {} catch {] feature to manage this message exception.

Comment: @LEFBE Well... in my case I don't need Try{} catch{}. I definitely do not have that registry key and/or value (tried various combinations) but never did I receive an exception because for me `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` prevents that. Perhaps you are running this without permission, but then.. you would get a different exception message. Is the code inside a module in your case perhaps? In that case, did you try `Import-Modue xxx -Force`, or tried in a fresh PowerShell instance after modifying the module?

Comment: Theo, I do not understand why your code do not provide a same result than you. However, solution proposed by you and @Scepticalist (try, catch) works as expected. 
I have to be brave and correct my code in this sense. This will avoid wasting your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually best to use error handling properly rather than try to disable it:

```
$Paths = 'HKLM:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment\', 'HKLM:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\environment\'

$Paths | ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        $CurPath = $_
        $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $CurPath  -Name 'Ins_ProductVersion' -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
        $RegError = "Error obtaining reg key: $_"
    }
    If ($hotfix) {
        [pscustomobject]@{RegPath=$_;Hotfix=$hotfix}
    }
    Else {
        [pscustomobject]@{RegPath=$_;Hotfix=$RegError}
    }
}
```

Or:

```
$Paths | ForEach-Object {
    Try {
        $CurPath = $_
        $hotfix = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $CurPath  -Name 'Ins_ProductVersion' -ErrorAction Stop
        [pscustomobject]@{RegPath=$_;Hotfix=$hotfix}
    }
    Catch {
        $RegError = "Error obtaining reg key: $_"
        [pscustomobject]@{RegPath=$_;Hotfix=$RegError}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Scepticalist, 

Thanks for your help. Indeed, your code manage error and address the needs, thanks for that :) 

However, do you thinking it's possible to ignore or not display the error message with my code ? 
Add 'try catch' need to change lot of lines in my code, if I can find a solution who can address this behavior faster than modify all the code, it could be nice for me ^^ 
Of course, if not, I will use yours

Thanks 
LEFBE

Comment: Nope, the problem is in the definition of the registry paths: `HKLM:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is wrong.